# How can I install japanese keyboard layout on windows 10 without admin privilages

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

So, I don't know Japanese, but I am trying to learn hiragana and katakana so that I can write my notes in them, cause it looks cool, and it makes it look like I know Japanese. I want to install the Japanese keyboard on my windows 10 device at school. The problem is, that I do not have any administrator privileges, nor do I have access to the windows store or *most* of the settings. Do you guys know how I can install the Japanese keyboard on my school device despite these restrictions? Maybe an AHK script? Cause I can use AHK if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Google Translate web site `https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&op=translate` and turn on the online input-method (Japanese keyboard simulator) by clicking `[あ ▾]` drop-down and check `あ konnichiha→こんにちは` menu.

In addition `✎日本語-手書き入力` is hand writing recognition.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to install the Japanese keyboard on my windows 10 device at school. The problem is, that I do not have any administrator privileges, nor do I have access to the windows store or most of the settings.

Sounds like the machine is managed by a group policy. Since you don't have access to an Administrator account on the domain you won't be able to do what you want. **You should seek the assistance of an network Administrator.** You still need permissions to install AHK. AHK also won't give you the permissions necessary to make system changes.

> Maybe an AHK script? Cause I can use AHK if needed.

The use of AHK won't change the system's keyboard layout.  Even if you run a portable version of AHK you still would not have the required permissions to install the language pack and/or keyboard layout. **Which means you still have to request your network administrator to install it for you**

> I was asking how to install some sort of Japanese IME on the school computer. Not necessarily the language pack specifically.

You will be unable to do this since you don't have access to an account with elevated permissions.